# HTML5, CSS3, Angular2, TypeScript For Rich Native (desktop) applications

Tags: javascript, node.js, wpf, html, qt

We are attempting to write a LOB application for a medical device. We expect the application to grow upto > 50k lines of code with a complex state machine, business logic and UI rendering. The choices are

1. Electron or NW.js using NodeJS, HTML5, CSS3, Angular2, TypeScript
2. QT
3. WPF

We have lot of internal javascript libraries and developers skilled with javascript. So our preference is to reuse as much as possible and go with option 1. Is option 1, mature enough to support developing complex desktop applications.

Which would be your preference if you are starting today.

Answer (score 2):

> HTML5, CSS3, Angular2, TypeScript For Rich Native (desktop) applications
>
> ...
>
> medical device

For what it's worth, this terrifies me.  I hope any critical functionality is being handled elsewhere.  If anything, because I do not trust anyone to audit all of the code you're about to dump into this **and** the code of the browser engine that's going to run it.

> Is option 1, mature enough to support developing complex desktop applications.

Yes, of course.  People do this every day.

> We have lot of internal javascript libraries and developers skilled with javascript.

JavaScript doesn't tie you to HTML5.  Folks have added QT bindings to Node.js before, as well as other libraries.

> We expect the application to grow upto > 50k lines of code

How could you possibly know this right now?  You haven't even decided what you're going to write it in.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I had done a similar project in a previous company using c#. hence know the complexity.